# Show that $K$ goes through these points

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with $A=(2,3)$, $B=(6,-1)$ and $C=(4,7)$.

The middle points of the sides are the following:$M_{AB}=\left (\frac{2+6}{2} , \frac{3+(-1)}{2}\right )=\left (4 , 1\right )$, $M_{AC}=\left (\frac{2+4}{2} , \frac{3+7}{2}\right )=\left (3 \mid 5\right )$ and $M_{BC}=\left (\frac{6+4}{2} , \frac{(-1)+7}{2}\right )=\left (5 ,3\right )$.

We have that the equation of the circle $K$ that passes by the points $M_{AB}$, $M_{AC}$ and $M_{BC}$ is \begin{equation*}\left (x - \frac{17}{6}\right )^2 + \left (y - \frac{17}{6}\right )^2 = \frac{170}{36}\end{equation*}

To determine the intersection point of the three height I did the following:

$h_a$ is orthogonal to $\vec{BC}$.

The slope of $\vec{BC}$ is $\frac{7-(-1)}{4-6}=\frac{8}{-2}=-4$.

The slope of $h_a$ is therefore $\frac{-1}{-4}=\frac{1}{4}$.

The equation of $h_a$ is: \begin{equation*}h_a: y-3 = \frac{1}{4}(x-2) \Rightarrow y-3 = \frac{1}{4}x-\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow y=\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{5}{2}\end{equation*}

$h_b$ is orthogonal to $\vec{CA}$.

The slope of $\vec{CA}$ is $\frac{3-7}{2-4}=\frac{-4}{-2}=2$.

the slope of $h_b$ is therefore $\frac{-1}{2}$.

The equation of $h_b$ is: \begin{equation*}h_a: y-(-1) = -\frac{1}{2}(x-6) \Rightarrow y+1 = -\frac{1}{2}x+3 \Rightarrow y = -\frac{1}{2}x+2\end{equation*}

For the intersection point we have $h_a=h_b$: 
\begin{equation*}\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{5}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}x+2 \Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}x=-\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow x=-\frac{4}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow x=-\frac{2}{3}\end{equation*}

Replacing this in $h_a$ we get: \begin{equation*}h_a: y=\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left (-\frac{2}{3}\right )+\frac{5}{2}= -\frac{1}{6}+\frac{5}{2}=\frac{14}{6}\end{equation*}

The intersection point is therefore \begin{equation*}H\left (-\frac{2}{3};\frac{14}{6}\right )\end{equation*}

$$$$

How could we show that $K$ goes through the middle point of $\overline{CH}$ and through the foot of the perpendicular from C to segment AB?

Could you give me a hint?

Comment: what "Wir betrachten die Dreiecksseite AB mit A=(2|3) und B=(6|−1)" means?

Comment: Nothing. I forgot to delete it when I translated the exercise statement. Do you have an idea? @Arnaldo

Comment: You already have the equation of $K$ and the middle point  $(C+H)/2$. What is so difficult?

Comment: So do we have to determine the middle point of $\overline{CH}$ and the foot of the perpendicular from C to segment AB? @Arnaldo

Comment: Yep, and test them at the equation of $K$.

Comment: the equation of a circle is $$(x-x_M)^2+(y-y_M)^2=R^2$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the intersection Point of the hights is H $$(-7/3;7/3)$$
and then we have $$\left(-2/3-7/6\right)^2+\left(7/3-7/6\right)^2=\left(\frac{85}{18}\right)^2$$

Comment: Ah so is the H that I found wrong?

Comment: you can Control it, the Point lies on the circle, indeed

Comment: Yes, I checked it and my point satisfies the equation of the circle. Do you have an other equation of the circle?

Comment: the difference is $$(\frac{85}{18})^2$$ if you don't believe it ask your teacher